# Aggregation of Maven two different Poms?

Tags: java, maven

In Maven is there any way i can aggregate different parent poms into one POM?
More Description About My Question :-

I am going to have two POM's

- One POM (a) is for Dependency Management.
- The other POM (b) is for Plugin Managment.

By clubbing(aggregating) these two Poms i will create One Parent POM and i will ask my other module team to use this.

i know Maven supports Inheritance . 
Using Inheritance we can achieve this requirement.

Is maven supports the Composition Of two different Poms ?
If Yes how i can i achieve this  ? 
How composition works in maven ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible for dependency management. In the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your POM "b" you can add a dependency to POM "a" with scope `import`.

From the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

> This scope is only used on a dependency of type pom in the  section. It indicates that the specified POM should be replaced with the dependencies in that POM's  section. Since they are replaced, dependencies with a scope of import do not actually participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

Comment: If two different poms having the same dependency with different versions how can i tell maven to take latest version instead of Old ? and vice versa also ( i.e take old instead of New means giving control to developer ) ?

Comment: @Maddy: This is a complicated topic (probably worth it's own detailed question). Shortly: 1. Every dependency explictly given in the dependency section is taken with the specific version. 2. If you have a corresponding dependency management entry, Maven takes the version from them for transitive dependencies. 3. If you have nothing like that, Maven takes the "nearest" version by dependency mediation (not necessarily the newest).

Comment: @JF thank you for comments. In maven we have concept called BOM  where we can achieve this (We can avoid the version missmatch as well ).This suggested by one of my friend

Comment: @Maddy BOMs are great, but only if you update them with new versions of your artifacts regularly.